# How to create a model and its generic relations on one page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have this setup:

```
class Observation(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    measurements = generic.GenericRelation(Measurement)

class Measurement(models.Model):
    variable = models.ForeignKey(Variable)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

These are simplified models of course. Measurement needs to be generic because it is also used elsewhere.

I want to make a page on which I can create an Observation *and* the related Measurements. The user should be able to add Measurements that are not yet present on the observation. I have a working ModelForm for Measurement.

I keep running into relations not existing, and I think I am making a silly mistake involving generic_inlinemodelform. I have searched but cannot find an example for this. Can anyone help me out, either by providing an example or linking to it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to save them using commit = False in your views.

**forms.py:**

```
class MeasurementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Measurement
        fields = ('variable', 'value')

class ObservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Observation
```

**template:**

```
<form method='POST>
    <legend>Observation</legend>
    {{ observation_form.as_p }}
    <legend>Measurement</legend>
    {{ measurement_form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

**views.py:**

```
def new_observation(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        observation_form = ObservationForm(request.POST)
        measurement_form = MeasurementForm(request.POST)
        if observation_form.is_valid() and measurement_form.is_valid():
            observation_instance = observation_form.save()
            measurement_instance = measurement_form.save(commit=False)
            measurement_instance.content_object = observation_instance
            measurement_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(observation_instance.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        observation_form = ObservationForm()
        measurement_form = MeasurementForm()

    context = { 'observation_form':observation_form,
                'measurement_form':measurement_form,}

    return render_to_response('add-observation.html', context,
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: That looks promising, I just need multiple measurements per observation so I'll try to translate this to formsets myself and then get back to you

Comment: hey @dyve it's been a while but I just stumbled upon this question. Could you please share how you eventually solved this?

Comment: Somehow never saw that last comment. I ended up using something based on this solution and a custom form generator that added the specific fields for each variable based on the observation instance.